# How to copy and paste a filtered table in Excel using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to copy only the visible data of a filtered Excel table to another range. My code so far is as shown:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Test Report.xlsx')
sht=wb.sheets('Sheet1')
sht.range('Table1').api.SpecialCells(12).copy
```

This does the copy and I can see the dashed lines around the table however I have no clue how to paste this somewhere else.

Comment: Have You tried sth like this: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy _ 
    destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy

Comment: @Teamothy Thats vba though im looking for an xlwings solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just figured to do it this way:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Test Report.xlsx')
sht=wb.sheets('Sheet1')
sht.range('Table1').api.SpecialCells(12).copy
sht.range('P2').select()
sht.api.paste
sht.api.Application.CutCopyMode=0
```